# Copying Tapes Data to Disk

Tags: tar, dd, cp, disk, tape

Is there any command which serves as copy paste option:
ABC on tape is copied as ABC on disk, without assigning a self label/name rather using the native file name.

I am using DD, TAR and Tcopy (for tapes only).

Any Help, I have million of files on tapes, can't rename each.

Comment: This looks like the end of an XY problem, what do you want to achive ? rename files on tape ? copy files from tape to disk and rename ?

Comment: You certaily can just go `cp /dev/tape /my/disk/file`

Comment: I want to achieve that if ABC (which is unknown to me) would come out as ABC rather specifying /my/disk/file this /file is my concern I want the system / command should do it.

Comment: Other words is it possible I can skip <file name> and system dumps what it finds on tape regardless name or format.

Answer (score 2):

Files on tapes do not have names. They are just *there* on the tape, stored one after the other. When you read a tape, you get a stream that consists of the contents of the file stored there. After that, if you read the tape again without rewinding first, you will get the next file, if there is one.

Therefore there is no such thing on tapes as " self label/name" or "native file name".

> Any Help, I have million of files on tapes, can't rename each.

Are you sure you have a million files on tapes? Usually, files on tapes are `tar` archives (or sometimes `cpio` archives or files in some other software-specific format). Those archives might contain a million files, but not the tape files themselves.

Comment: Tape may hold 1-2000 files, if recording goes fine then all are stored as FFID1, FFID2...FFIDn. 

Problem is when some files are discarded, now FFID1 could be FFID5 if first 4 files are missing.

I use this script to copy data from tape to disk, it labels the output as per given instruction, as I am new to Linux so can't figure out how to resolve it, please help:

#!/bin/sh
i=1
j=$1
if [ $2 -ge "1" ] ;
then
        i=$2
        j=`expr $1 + $2`
fi
fn=''
mt -f /dev/nst1 rewind
while [ $i -lt $j ]
do
   fn='FFID'$i'.segd'
   dd if=/dev/nst1 ibs=32767 of=$fn
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done
exit

Comment: Yes that's specific format SEGD.

Comment: Other words is it possible I can skip <file name> and system dumps what it finds on tape regardless name or format.

Comment: I can't understand what you are getting it, because you talk about deleting files on a tape but there is no such thing as deleting a file on a tape. There is only overwriting it with another file, and if you do that then all other files that come after it on the tape will also be gone because they don't start at the right place.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase it. 10 files with names 1, 2, 3 ... 10 were selected, but 4, 6, 9 were not written. Now when extracting the data DD will assign file labels/names 1...7 sequentially. And I have to read all files to rename them as 3 of them were not written. Is there any way that system (using DD or else) detects the names of written files and assign these names accordingly to the extracted out files? I guess it's more clear...... many thanks for your kind time.

Comment: No, impossible, because *files on tapes do not have names**. There is no such thing as renaming a file on a tape. If there are seven files on the tape then there are just simply seven files on the tape, one after the other. They are not numbered, and they are not called 1,2,3,5,7,8,10.